# App_Pool_Alert Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I have written a power shell script which is used to monitor the status of IIS  app pools. With current method whenever any pool goes down it throws me an alert that pool is stopped and after that it starts the pool again send email stating that pool is up. Since i have around 50 servers so number of mails are coming in bulk which causes spam sometimes. Could some one help me here so that script will scan the pool directory and place the result in a text/html file and send me the list that these pools are down in mail. Please find script below:-

```
###################################Declear Servers in text file##############################################

$Servers = Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\server.txt

################ Scans each server and import IIS web-administration module##################################

$Servers | ForEach-Object {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
            Import-Module WebAdministration
            cd IIS:/AppPools
            $CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
            $ApplicationPools = dir
foreach ($item in $ApplicationPools)
{
    $ApplicationPoolName = $item.Name
    $ApplicationPoolStatus = Get-WebAppPoolState $ApplicationPoolName
    If($ApplicationPoolStatus.value -eq "Stopped")

         {
            send-mailmessage -to "vvv@gmail.com" -from "xxx@gmail.com" -subject "Application Pool:- $ApplicationPoolName is Down on $CompName " -Body "$ApplicationPoolName is down. Please check IIS/Event logs for RCA." -SmtpServer ###########          

            Start-WebAppPool -Name $ApplicationPoolName

            send-mailmessage -to "vvv@gmail.com" -from "xxx@gmail.com" -subject "Application Pool:- $ApplicationPoolName is Up on $CompName " -Body "$ApplicationPoolName is Up and running fine." -SmtpServer #############         

          }

}

}}

##################################### End of Script ##########################################################
```

Comment: Why not just write to a string array in your IF statement and then at the end, if it's not empty, email that in the body of an email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would rewrite the script:

```
###################################Declear Servers in text file##############################################

$Servers = Get-Content C:\server.txt

################ Scans each server and import IIS web-administration module##################################

$SMPTServer = "mail.server.com"
$result = "The following application pools were restarted:`n`n" # default output 

$Servers | ForEach-Object {
    $result += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { # add output of scriptblock to $result
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        cd IIS:/AppPools
        $CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
        $ApplicationPools = dir
        foreach ($item in $ApplicationPools)
        {
            $ApplicationPoolName = $item.Name
            $ApplicationPoolStatus = Get-WebAppPoolState $ApplicationPoolName
            If($ApplicationPoolStatus.value -eq "Stopped")
                {    
                    Write-Output "Server $CompName - Application pool $ApplicationPoolName is Down - Restarting`n" # any action is added to otput
                    Start-WebAppPool -Name $ApplicationPoolName
                }
        }

    }
}
if ($result -ne "The following application pools were restarted:`n`n") { # If any action was taken send mail with $result
    send-mailmessage -to "vvv@gmail.com" -from "xxx@gmail.com" -subject "Application Pool Maitenance" -Body $result -SmtpServer $SMPTServer
}
##################################### End of Script ##########################################################
```

First define a $result variable, in this case just a string.

Withing your scriptblock, you can write anything to piped output using Write-Output. This output is returned from Ivoke-Command and added to the $result variable.

At the end of your script check if $result variable has changed and send it as a body of an email if required.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I tested the above logic and its working but problem is result is coming in a mail i.e, if 100 websites going down it is sending one mail listing all 100. When i tried to write the output in a text file script is not writing the results of remote computers . Any idea related to this how can i write the output in a text file so that with attachment command i ca send that to mail.

Comment: I am using Out-File -FilePath "C:\server\" command to write output after foreach ($item in $ApplicationPools) function execution.